# how to disable the new popup file-picker on :w

Tags: command-line, save, popup-menu

If I try to write a file under a new name, instead of being able to edit an existing name provided by file-completion, I get a pop-up that only lets me select an existing one.

I saw a description of this problem in the internet that was similar but involved the arrow keys, and the solution required remapping them! I use vi map, you can't remap j/k/l/h.  Or do I misunderstand

Comment: what exactly did you do? How did you get the popup? What keys did you press?

Comment: after making a change the file: ":w c<tab>".  At that point, I got a popup listing files starting with c and one was supplied on the command line.  When I start to cruise to where I wanted to make the change ("hhh"), it moved the cursor in the pop-up.  In the meantime, I have a work-around, but ....  The work around is to use the backspace key to delete the last character (where the commandline cursor is).  This disables the popup and I can then move to where I want to make a change

Comment: Does Ctrl-C/ESC make a difference?

Comment: Well, ESC naturally aborts the command line, presumably ctrl-c, too.  ... yep, that, too

Comment: Ah, I looked it up in the documentation. Read `:h wildmenu` and use `Ctrl-E`

Comment: Thank you.  I couldn't find it in the docu but it probably wouldn't have occurred to me to look into "wildmenu" - when, in fact, it's a perfectly appropriate name ...  Anyway, I'll set "nowildmenu" in my .vimrc file

Comment: So, that's solved, thank you.  Do I have to do anything to show that?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt and/or OP should post an answer that explains the solution, which can then be voted on or accepted

Comment: @D.BenKnoble done

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the documentation at [:h 'wildmenu'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27wmnu%27) you can type

> CTRL-E:  end completion, go back to what was there before
> selecting a match.

Note: To have the popup menu displayed, and a recent enough enough vim (v8.2.4325 or newer) and you need to configure Vim to make use of it:

```
:set wildoptions=pum
:set wildmode=full
```